# Complex number problem becomes huge when using formulas - is there any workaround?

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is an equation I need to solve for $z$ where $z$ is a complex number.(I need to show which complex numbers are solution for this problem):
$$\left|\frac{1+z}{1-i\bar z}\right| = 1$$
Here are formulas I am using:
$|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$;  $\bar z = a-bi$.
So at first I need to simplify $\frac{1+z}{1-i\bar z}$ to $a+bi$ form. 
After a few operations here is what I came up with:
$$\frac{1+z}{1-i\bar z} = \frac{1+a-b-2ab+(b-b^2+a+a^2)i}{1+b^2+2b+a^2}$$ where $z = a+bi$. It seems overcomplicated already and I still have to find modulus of this number which will complicate it even more. The question is - in such a case should I try to count this that way anyway or is there any simpler solution which I haven't noticed?

Comment: Rewrite it. $\left\lvert \frac{a}{b}\right\rvert = 1$ is equivalent to $\lvert a\rvert = \lvert b\rvert$. Then it is usually much easier to work with the square of the modulus than with the modulus itself.

Comment: Thanks, I think I managed to solve that now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two complex numbers $z_1\ne z_2$, the equation $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$ says that the distance between $z$ and $z_1$ is equal to the distance between $z$ and $z_2$; the solution is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining $z_1$ and $z_2$. With a little easy work, your equation can be put in that form.

First, clearing fractions gets the equation in the form
$$|1+z|=|1-i\bar z|.$$
The left side is
$$|1+z|=|z-(-1)|,$$
the distance from $z$ to $-1$.
The right side needs a bit more work. Using the identities $|zw|=|z||w|$ and $|\bar z|=|z|$, we get
$$|1-i\bar z|=|\overline{1-i\bar z}|=|1+iz|=|i(-i+z)|=|i||-i+z|=1\cdot|z-i|=|z-i|.$$
So your equation simplifies to
$$|z-(-1)|=|z-i|,$$
and the solution set is the set of all points equidistant from $-1$ and $i$, which is the line $y=-x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z = x+iy$ then your equation is (see Daniel's hint)
$$
(1+x)^2+y^2 = (1+y)^2 + x^2
$$

So the solutions is 
$$
z = r (1+i)
$$
where $r$ can be any real number.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $(1+x)^2+y^2 = (1-y)^2 + x^2$?

Comment: @user36346 You're right. So $r(1-i)$.